# Replay attack in Wi-Fi (802.11) network

Tags: network, wifi, attack-prevention

I am trying to create a small smartphone activated lock for my house via Wi-Fi.
The setup is like this:

- The solenoid of the lock is connected to an esp8266 that acts as an access point, and has an HTTP (or WebSocket) server on it.
- The smart phone connects to the access point and sends a GET request, then the lock opens (or the phone sends some string in the case of WebSocket).

The questions are: Since I am always doing the same operation exactly the same, can someone sniff the packets sent and perform a replay attack?

As far as I know, the encryption key changes each session, but what if I am still connected to the network? Can someone then pretend to be me?

Are there any countermeasures done in Wi-Fi networks?

Comment: What encryption scheme is the WiFi using?

Comment: It is using WPA2-Personal protocol

Comment: As for the encryption itself it is AES-CCMP

Comment: Slide 15 of [this](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~mgunes/cs450/cs450sp11/student/WPA2vulnerabilities.pptm) seems to point to replay detection existing

Comment: This is pretty easy to handle within your GET/WebSocket framework with a handshake: the first request sent is "ClientHello", including a lock protocol version number for future compatibility; the reply is "LockHello", which includes 8-12 bytes of (ideally cryptographic) random number generated by the Lock, and the response is "ClientOpen", which has an HMAC authentication based on the random number sent in LockHello.  Now replays have a fantastically small chance of succeeding.  The Lock has to hold on to the random numbers it sent for a reasonable fraction of a second, after that, start over

Comment: Thank you for your answers!!
The handshake thing is quite effective in my case I think, but I have two questions about that : 
1-What do you mean by "Protocol version number"?
I am not sure what do you mean by that
2-If I got it right: the lock sends a random number in the LockHello , so isn't it enough to send the number back in the ClientOpen? why use HMAC?